# Custom routes in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I want to made a custom routing option in codeigniter:

The request to:

```
http://www.example.com/api/xxx
```

will redirect to controllers in folder **api**

```
controllers/api/yyy
```

And the value of **xxx** should be - **1.0** or **2.0** or **3.0** ... and the value of **yyy** should be - **api_1_0.php** or **api_1_0.php** or **api_3_0** ...

For Eg: `api/1.0` will redirect to `controllers/api/api_1_0.php`

I tried:

```
$route['api/(:any)'] = "api/api_$1";
```

But it not working.

Comment: Its not clear what you want.write the full path of your redirect url

Comment: when requesting http://www.example.com/api/2.0 i need to redirect to the controller - api_2_0.php (which inside api folder in controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$route['api/(\d+)\.(\d+)'] = "api_$1_$2";//if your controller inside controller folder
```

or

```
$route['api/(\d+)\.(\d+)'] = "api/api_$1_$2";//if your controller inside controller/api folder
```

Answer (score 2):

The routing with `(:any)` will not serve your purpose.

You may use a regular expression instead.

If you need to route

```
http://www.example.com/api/1.0
```

to

```
/api/api_1_0
```

The you can use the routing

```
$route["api/(\d+)\.(\d+)"] = "api/api_$1_$2";
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: not working... Note that api is a folder and api_1_0 is the controller file.

Comment: Just changed the routing code a bit. Tested and it's working now.